# How do I add/create additional end points in MS botframework

Tags: node.js, botframework

We are trying to develop a bot for two channels WebChat and Skype for Business using MS bot framework using Nodejs. We have hosted the bot on Azure and already the default end point "/api/messages" registered. We are now making a third party API call asynchronously and we like to create another custom end point where the callback can be retrieved and then somehow the response are shown back to the user. So let's say 100 users are interacting with the BOT and thus making 100 async calls. When the callbacks are returned, we want them returned to this new endpoint and then somehow the response should show to the respective user/window. We have a total of four different API calls that are made based on the user context. How would I go about achieving this feature?

Answer (score 0):

First, regarding Skype for Business, please note the [following](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-skypeforbusiness?view=azure-bot-service-4.0):

> Skype for Business channel in Bot Framework is being deprecated on June 30, 2019.
>
> No new bots will be able to add Skype for Business channel after that date. Existing bots will continue to work until October 31, 2019. Microsoft Teams is the preferred communication tool from Microsoft. Learn how to [connect your bot to Microsoft Teams](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/bots).

That being said, if I understand your question correctly, you can easily create other endpoints in the same manner as the 'api/messages' endpoint. Checkout BotBuilder-Samples no. [16.proactive-messages](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/16.proactive-messages) that demonstrates using a second endpoint to initiate a proactive message.

Essentially, your code would look like this:

```js
// Listen for incoming activities and route them to your bot main dialog.
server.post('/api/messages', (req, res) => {
    adapter.processActivity(req, res, async(turnContext) => {
        // route to main dialog.
        await bot.run(turnContext);
    });
});
// Listen for incoming notifications and send proactive messages to users.
server.get('/api/notify', async(req, res) => {
    for (let conversationReference of Object.values(conversationReferences)) {
        await adapter.continueConversation(conversationReference, async turnContext => {
            await turnContext.sendActivity('proactive hello');
        });
    }
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.write('<html><body><h1>Proactive messages have been sent.</h1></body></html>');
    res.end();
```

Hope of help!